# JPA with Hibernate: .... org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, group-by, spring-data-jpa

I have a @ManyToMany relationship described as follows:

```
FOO
-----------------------
FOO_ID             
    ........

FOO_BARS
--------------------
BAR_ID          
FOO_ID          

BAR
-------------------- 
BAR_ID              
    .......


@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
public class FOO  
{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(....)
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    @Column(name = "FOO_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10)
    private int fooId;

    public int getFooId()
    {
    ......
    }

    public void setFooId(final int fooId)
    {
    ......;
    }

    .....

    @@ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(name = "FOO_BARS", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "FOO_ID", nullable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "BAR_ID", nullable = false) })
    private List<Bar> bars; 

    public List<Bar> getBars()
    {
        ......
    }

    public void setBars(final List<Bar> bars)
    {
        ......
    }

    public Bar addBar(Bar value)
    {
      .....
    }
    ......
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BAR")
public class Bar 
{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(...)
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    @Column(name = "BAR_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 9)
    private int barid;

    public int getBard()
    {
        .....
    }

    public void setBarId(final int barId)
    {
        .....
    }

    .....

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bar")
    private List<Foo> foos;

    public List<Foo> getFoos()
    {
        ....
    }

    public void setFooList(final List<Foo> foos)
    {
        ....
    }

    public Foo addFoo(final Foo foo)
    {
       .......
    }


.....
}
```

I have an sql query which I can successfully run to select ALL foos matching a list of provided barIds. This changes according to the provided barIds but is of the format:

```
SELECT f.* FROM foo f 
WHERE 
.....
AND f.foo_id IN
(
  SELECT fb.foo_id FROM foo_bars fb
            WHERE fb.bar_id IN ( 69, 332)
            GROUP BY  fb.foo_id
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT fb.bar_id) =  2
);
```

As entitities don't use a linking table, my issue is in translating this into a query to run using hibernate syntax.
I have tried the following:

```
SELECT f FROM Foo AS f  
WHERE 
.....
AND f.fooId  IN  
(  
    SELECT  b.foos.fooId FROM f.bars b  
    WHERE  b.barid  IN (:barids) 
    GROUP BY  b.foos.fooId  
    HAVING  COUNT  (  DISTINCT  b.barid  )  = 2 
)
```

This results in the following error.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [bar2_.BAR_ID.foos] with element property reference [fooId]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In class Foo you mapped ManyToOne association with List<Bar>

Comment: Thank you Tkachuck_Evgen. It was a typo during transcription. Corrected now.